# Why is my interactive image glitchy on ONLY internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**My issue:**
I've made myself an image map/interactive image of sorts and it's working perfectly on Chrome, safari and Firefox. However, when I try it on the dreaded internet explorer, it's really glitchy. The little points are supposed to expand into larger boxes, on internet explorer it either doesn't work or messes up in the process.

**See the problem:**
See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnaeaxge/14/),
See this [website](https://www.thehealthytray.com) for a better idea (my code is active on here).

**What part of my code could be causing this it to mess up on IE?** Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML and CSS:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
html 
  color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.description {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

div, img, footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;

}

strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dff3fd;
}
a:visited {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
li.active a, a:hover, a:active {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
  position: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 1190px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #dff3fd;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
        </style>
 </head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<div class="distribution-map">


    <button class="map-point" style="top:24%;left:26.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>details</p>
              <iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5MgBikgcWnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:26%;left:49%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
   <button class="map-point" style="top:27.3%;left:71.4%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:63.5%;left:31.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:65%;left:56%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
     <button class="map-point" style="top:68%;left:74%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hehe. Internet Explorer.

Comment: Hahaha, it's always internet explorer

Comment: This is a great example of why its not a great idea to try to perform major functions through css transitions and filters.  Not very cross-browser friendly. That being said, I see you fixed your click issue!  Similar problem...trying to use css `focus` for an onclick event.

Comment: Hello again @ChrisM! I'm going to definitely try and use some JQuery next time I do something like this haha. Yes, that part's fixed now:) Can you think of any solution to my issue here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that <=IE9 can not use transitions.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

There is a polyfill that might help though here: http://ecsstender.org/extensions/css3-transitions/index.html