# How to set up a css specifically for internet explorer and edge?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having big issues with internet explorer being a pain and glitching out on my [website](http://www.thehealthytray.com), (see other question/my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369965/why-is-my-interactive-image-glitchy-on-only-internet-explorer?noredirect=1#comment60377309_36369965)).

**My problem:**
I have an interactive image on this [website](http://www.thehealthytray.com) that acts like an image map - there are points all over the image and when the mouse hovers over one, it expands into a bigger box (this contains information. I have 6 points on the page. This works perfectly in all browsers apart from IE & Edge.

**What happens in IE/edge:**
The points are very glitchy and don't expand properly. Although the bottom 3 points do work fairly well for some reason.

This is why I'm thinking of creating a separate style sheet for IE.

I think the only way to do it is to create a completely different section of css, specifically for internet explorer. I would then like to control the css specifically for IE from my HTML, rather than having a separate stylesheet.

**How would I go about doing this?**

**This [IE issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369965/why-is-my-interactive-image-glitchy-on-only-internet-explorer?noredirect=1#comment60377309_36369965) has been plaguing me for ages now, if anyone knows the answer I'd be overjoyed.**

Any help will be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D : Sorry for the confusion, I hope it's slightly better now?

Comment: What's unclear is this: Are you asking how you can tell IE to use different CSS or are you asking how you should change your CSS so it works with IE? The former is pretty easy, the latter is impossible to answer with the information you've given so far.

Comment: @mmgross Sorry for my bad wording, I've identified the probelm I'm currently facing:  I've asked it in a more focused question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388746/youtube-iframe-embed-code-not-working-well-with-ie-edge). If you could help at all that would be great:)

Answer (score 1):

type in head(in html)

```
<!--[if IE]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css">

<![endif]-->
```

and then create ie.css(or what name you want to have) and here everything you write will be performed only for IE browser(all versions).

If you want only for a specific version of IE ( ie8, ie7..), replace from  IE with "IE 8" or "IE 7"(without quotes).
Also here is more codes:

```
<!-- [if gte IE 8]>
<link>
<![endif]-->
```

gte= greater than equal, and you can replace gte with: lt=less than, lte=less than equal, gt=greater than.

*Sorry for english*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would that not just add a comment which the browsers wouldn't read? Also could i code the ie.css directly into my html with style tags, if so how would I distinguish it from the main css? You're english is good:) Thanks

Comment: This is a special comment and it will be read only by ie.  I think you can type the code in html with style tag.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a go. Thank you R Catalin:)

Comment: It's worth noting that IE conditional comments are deprecated and not supported in IE 10, 11 and Edge. Related link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx